# How to put the scroll at the bottom of the div on click

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

Why the scroll code is not working? I want the scroll to go to the bottom when i click on `$('#openDiv')`.

Example: When you enter in a chat room here on stackoverflow you see that the scroll is at the bottom by default, i want this.

I also tried to put the scroll code outside the click function, but it's not working...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#openDiv').on('click', function(){
    $('#openDiv').hide();
    $('#closeDiv').show();
    
    ///////// NOT WORKING /////////
    $("#mainDiv").animate({
      scrollTop: $('#mainDiv').prop("scrollHeight")
    }, 1000);
    ///////// NOT WORKING /////////
    
    $("#mainDiv").show();
  });
  
  $('#closeDiv').on('click', function(){
    $('#closeDiv').hide();
    $("#mainDiv").hide();
    $('#openDiv').show();
  });
  
});
```

```css
#mainDiv {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #2A2A2A;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: none;
}

#divText {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #555555;
  height: 20px;
}
#divTextEnd{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
}

#openDiv{
  background-color: green;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
}

#closeDiv{
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button id="openDiv">Open div</button>
<button id="closeDiv">Close div</button>

<div id="mainDiv">

  <div id="divText">
    <h5>text</h5>
  </div>
  <div id="divText">
    <h5>text</h5>
  </div>
  <div id="divText">
    <h5>text</h5>
  </div>
  <div id="divText">
    <h5>text</h5>
  </div>
  <div id="divTextEnd">
    <h5>text</h5>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you call `$('#mainDiv').prop("scrollHeight")`, `#mainDiv` is hidden with `display: none;`. Such an element has a `scrollHeight` of 0.

Show `#mainDiv` before trying to scroll it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#openDiv').on('click', function() {
    $('#openDiv').hide();
    $('#closeDiv').show();

    $("#mainDiv").show();

    $("#mainDiv").animate({
      scrollTop: $('#mainDiv').prop("scrollHeight")
    }, 1000);
  });

  $('#closeDiv').on('click', function() {
    $('#closeDiv').hide();
    $("#mainDiv").hide();
    $('#openDiv').show();
  });

});
```

```css
#mainDiv {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #2A2A2A;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: none;
}

#divText {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #555555;
  height: 20px;
}

#divTextEnd {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
}

#openDiv {
  background-color: green;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
}

#closeDiv {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button id="openDiv">Open div</button>
<button id="closeDiv">Close div</button>

<div id="mainDiv">

  <div id="divText">
    <h5>text</h5>
  </div>
  <div id="divText">
    <h5>text</h5>
  </div>
  <div id="divText">
    <h5>text</h5>
  </div>
  <div id="divText">
    <h5>text</h5>
  </div>
  <div id="divTextEnd">
    <h5>text</h5>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```